# Como resolver TemplateSyntaxError em django?

Tags: html, python, django

Esse é o meu trecho de código, e como podem ver, fecho o bloco no final, porém continuo recebendo o erro

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <form>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title of the page">
            <label for="textArea">Page content:</label>
            <!--ERRO AQUI-->
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="15">         
                {% print(f"teste") %}   
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Post!</button>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Erro:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /editPage
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'print(f"teste")', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
TemplateSyntaxError at /editPage
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'print(f"teste")', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este erro remova a linha que possui o texto:

```
{% print(f"teste") %}
```

Se você deseja imprimir valores dentro do seu template a maneira correta é colocar os valores entre duas chaves (`{{ 'valor' }}`).

Segue um exemplo utilizando o seu código:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Edit page
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
        <form>
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title of the page">
            <label for="textArea">Page content:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="15">         
                {{ 'teste' }}   
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Post!</button>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

O jinja2 (que é a linguagem de template do django) diz que para definir blocos é utilizado a sintaxe:

```
{% block %}
{% endblock %}
```

Supondo que a variável `users` é uma lista em python, poderiamos iterar sobre os valores desta lista da seguinte forma:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
  <li><a href="{{ user.url }}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Porém para fazer a impressão dos valores e variáveis (vindas do python) deve-se utilizar os duplas chaves.

Segue um link para aprender mais sobre o [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/).

Comment: Muito obrigado!